# How can I set hotkeys for script on/off?

Tags: 16.04, scripts, shortcut-keys

I have this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(nvidia-settings -q '[gpu:0]/DigitalVibrance[DFP-1]' | grep 'Attribute.*1023\.') ]]
then

    nvidia-settings -a '[gpu:0]/DigitalVibrance[DFP-1]=0' > /dev/null
    echo "Vibrance Disabled"
else 

    nvidia-settings -a '[gpu:0]/DigitalVibrance[DFP-1]=1023' > /dev/null
    echo "Vibrance Enabled"
fi
```

How can I set hotkeys for this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Unity, this GIF will demonstrate the steps:
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58095/discussion-on-answer-by-firefaced-how-i-can-set-hotkey-for-script-on-off).